# toggle list items on and of with angular and ionic lists

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I have a nice sorted list showing types of cars sorted by car brand. i.e.

```
Bmw
____
318
745

Porsche
____
911
965
```

I am trying to figure out how to toggle on and off the items underneath a carbrand, so that you get for instance

```
BMW
___
Porsche
____
911
965
```

but i am getting stuck. I have created a css class hiderecommendation (display:none), and showrwcommendation (display:block). And now i am tryning the ng-click class, however i get stuck. Anybody see what i am doing wrong?

```
 <ion-content  class="has-subheader">
    <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
    <div class="category" ng-repeat="(key, value) in recommendation | filter: query | groupBy : 'textID' ">
      <ion-item ng-click="toggleRecommendation(item)" class="item item-text-wrap"> 
      <span>{{key}}</span>
      </ion-item>  

      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in value" ng-class="item.recommendation ? 'showrecommendation' : 'hiderecommendation'">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <span>{{item.Recommendation}}</span> 
        </div>
     </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't break your head when there's a working 3rd party Ionic plugin.

It's called Ion tree list and you can do with it precisely what you want, find it [here](http://www.gajotres.net/must-have-plugins-for-ionic-framework/2/#pl22).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your referral! Glad to see this is considered useful, there're still some challenges pendant, as 'drag and drop' functionality of items. PRs are very welcome! Thanks again.